# who should I choose for a heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Recently I've completed my first heist. I used the better hacker, the worse driver and the worse gunner(or whatever he's called). As a result I got:

> **1)** we had enough time to steal all the items(thanks to a good hacker)

.

> **2)** one guy fell of the bike when we were running away. Result: lost around 1.4 mil(down to 2.8 from 4.2)

.

> **3)** the driver wasn't sure where to go, so he chose random direction, which appeared to be the right one.

.

> And 2 of the crew got +25% skill I think after the completion of the mission. Looks like the one who fell down with a bike got nothing.

So the question is: should I take the better ones from the beginning or is it better to take the worse ones and let them become better?

Comment: I chose the same team and got the same result. I get the feeling we wouldn't have been chased on LS river, if I had chosen a better driver, though...

Comment: @Nolonar - Even if you select the best driver you still will get chased that is part of the story.  How do I know this?  I selected the best choices for every choice and still got chased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use all of the cheapest ones. The police come after you anyway, so you still have time to smash all the cases. The cheap gunman falls off his bike, so drive over the money he drops and his money gets added to the pot, but you don't have to share it with him.

The mission is still the same, except you get more money.

Oh, and the more expensive driver just chooses dirtbikes instead of the racing bikes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your preference.  Better people from the start means you're more likely to walk away with a bigger take, but you have to pay bigger cuts.  Less skilled means you may not have as a big a take, and it may be harder, but you lose less in paying out cuts.  If you're okay with not having dramatic takes right away, then pick less skilled guys and build them up on easy heists.  Then when they have high skills, you do jobs smoothly without paying out as much.

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't important to complete the mission then choose the one who is cheapest. If they are important to complete the mission then spend more on them. I don't think there is any special formula for who to choose, but if the heist requires a lot of driving then you probably don't want to pick someone with little experience; at the same time you could probably get by without the best driver too.